# how to solve this homogeneous differention equation ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

$dy/dx= (2x+3y+4)/(4x+6y+5)$. I am trying to solve this homogeneous Ds, but don't understand how to solve it. I believe the first step is to solve this:

1) $y=u x$
2) $dy/dx = u+x \cdot du/dx$ then what ??

Comment: Please use the built-in LaTeX support to display your equations properly. It is hard to see, which part of the formula belongs to the fraction. It looks like this is **not** a homogeneous ODE.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint***: let $u=2x+3y$ then use separation of variables